# Using Curl to upload files to S3 using Signature v4

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, curl

I'm trying to upload a file to s3 using this curl command (can't use awscli)

```
src_file=/path/to/file.png
dest_file=test_image.png
bucket=mybucket.com
s3Key="<key>"
s3Secret="<secret>"
contentsha=`openssl sha256 ${src_file} | awk '{print $NF}'`

curl https://${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/${dest_file} \
-H "x-amz-content-sha256: ${contentsha}" \
--aws-sigv4 "aws:amz:us-east-1:s3" \
--user "${s3Key}:${s3Secret}" \
--upload-file "${src_file}" \
--insecure
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It would appear that curl doesn't include `x-amz-content-sha256` when creating the canonical header string to sign.